# Какая функция вызывается при скрытии Dialog?

Tags: java, android

Вобщем такой вопрос: при нажатии на кнопку диалога приложение должно закрытся. А что делать если пользователь нажмет не на диалог а мимо него (сам так делаю). Какая функция вызывается?

Comment: не могу сейчас доподлинно проверить, но почему бы вам просто не поставить System.out'ы в обоих вариантах (пользователь нажал "да" и "нет")?

Answer (score 1):

```
dialogAdd.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Здесь делай что тебе угодно 


    }
});
```

Comment: Ошибка: You can not set Dialog's OnCancelListener or OnDismissListener

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите отследить, когда диалог был закрыт, то у DialogFragment можно переопределить метод [*onDismiss()*](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29).

Если же нужно отследить только когда диалог был отменен нажатием back, либо "мимо диалога" - то это метод [*onCancel()*](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCancel%28android.content.DialogInterface%29)

В случае с DialogFragment, нужно переопределять эти методы, а не ставить OnDismissListener/OnCancelListener на диалог.